# Java-Android-Process time in IF statement (real time code)

Tags: java, android, if-statement, real-time, processing

I have 2 codes snippets with the same condition:

```
boolean A =true;
boolean B =true;
```

very simple.
But Which one of the 2 codes will be faster ,only in this case,not when one of them is false

first code:

```
  if(A&&B){
  doSomthing();
  }
```

second code:

```
if(A){
     if(B){
  doSomthing();
  }}
```

Remember: A and B are true.

I just modify and optimize my code that do real time rendering,and every millisecond   could be big improvment in terms of very large arrays.

**I guess that if A=false, the second code will be faster. but if B=false the first will be faster?

**more info:** A and B in my case is just two conditions like:

```
(mNumber==5&&arr[j]!=19)
```

**results after test it:** with the conditions:    A=true; and     B=true; there is no really different  between the 2 codes( mixing results in term of nano seconds-kind of equels results)

Comment: OK, why not just try it out?

Comment: first,you right.second,i will try it out and edit my question with the answer

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is very likely to turn these into identical code. Even in "real-time" code, don't code things like this based on what you think will be fastest; write clear code, and then profile if you think there's a problem.

In this case, `if(a & b)` is significantly clearer, so use that. (It will also be the faster option if the compiler generates different code, because there's only one comparison and jump needed. Note that this is different from the canonical handling of `a && b`.)

**Edit:** It looks like you edited your question to change the condition from `&` to `&&`. Short-circuiting is a good idea when the arguments are expensive to evaluate, but if they're really both `boolean` values, `AND`ing them together is almost always cheaper.

Comment: they are not really  boolean value. it is two condition like (a==5&&b[j]!=19) for instance.